# A plane is headed N 50 E with a speed of 800 km/h. A west wind causes it to travel N 56 E. Find resultant?

Tags: calculus

How do i picture this? Where does this west wind fit in? where does the resultant go? (does this diagram even make sense?)

[image]

is this diagram better? where does the resultant go?

Answer (score 1):

Using standard angle notation to make the trig work nicely: angles measured counterclockwise from the positive x axis

The plane is ***headed*** at $40^\circ$ flying at $800 \text{ km/hr}$, so the north and east components of the plane's velocity, $P$, relative to the air, are:$$P_{east}=800 \cos(40^\circ)$$ $$P_{north}=800 \sin(40^\circ)$$ The velocity of the wind is W, blowing **from** the west, so adding the air velocities to the plane velocities gives the the east and north velocities over the ground, $G$:$$G_{east}=800 \cos(40^\circ)+W$$ $$G _{north}=800 \sin(40^\circ)$$

But we know the direction of the velocity over the ground. so:$$\frac{G _{north}}{G_{east}}=\frac{800 \sin(40^\circ)}{800 \cos(40^\circ)+W}=\tan(34^\circ)$$This looks messy, but it's easy to solve for W, the only unknown.  Then use Pythagoras to combine $G _{north}$ and $G _{east}$ to find the magnitude of $G$...

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is fine. As the wind is (from the) West, the North velocity is unchanged. You need to find the new East velocity needed to make the new angle.

Comment: so the west wind is irrelevant?

Comment: i made a new diagram^^^ where does the resultant form?

Comment: It is what increases the East velocity. You don't have to calculate the wind velocity and don't have the data to do so.

Comment: but we have 2 east velocities?

Comment: i dont understand how the west wind factors into the resultant?

Comment: Point $B$ and $D$ should be the same.  They are the same distance North of $A$.  The resultant is then $AB$ or $AD$.  The first vector is $AC$, the plane velocity.  The second is $CB$, the velocity imparted by the wind.